# hide labels in a table (LIBGDX)

Tags: libgdx, uilabel

- I have a table and added labels row by row in a specific order 
  Say 5 labels : "1","2","3","4","5"
- Now I would like to hide Label 3 temporarly and also the space used by the label 3.
- Later I would like to show it again. Depends on the state.

How can I do this properly ?

I could just remove all actors from the table and add them again, but I guess this is timeconsuming doing this in a act(delta) step.

Is there an elegant way to only manipulate that label ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the reference to the label when you add it to the table. Then you can call `setVisible()` on this refernce to hide or show the label.

Note that hiding the label will not change the layout of the table: the space your label needs will stay blank. This could be the intended behaviour. If you don't want that, you have to `remove()` the label from the cell and set it back later. In this case, you also need to keep the reference to the cell.